Ansible - understanding how to display certain parts of the gather facts
I'm struggling to understand how to display only a particular fact from Ansible gather facts data...or how to drill down in dictionary items just to display one item
As an example, I only want this fact "ansible_default_ipv4 . address" to appear at the output:
"address": "172.22.27.74"

I tried the following but didn't get the results:
ansible all -i ostts5istrp01, -m setup -a "filter=ansible_default_ipv4.address"

I can only get the full dictionary when using filter= ansible_default_ipv4
So how can I drill down on facts and subfacts to display only one line?
Examples, I would like to extract:
ansible_facts.ansible_bond0.active

or
ansible_facts.ansible_bond0.features.esp_hw_offload

How can I do that?

Are you looking for the ad-hoc command or for a playbook?

for adhoc please. if in playbook then that might help also for me to understand how it drills down the values

filter can filter facts, but can't extract keys. To extract some specific keys you can use pipe with jq, for example:
ansible all -i ostts5istrp01, -m setup -a "filter=ansible_bond0" | jq -r '.ansible_facts.ansible_bond0.active'

or
ansible all -i ostts5istrp01, -m setup -a "filter=ansible_bond0" | jq -r '.ansible_facts.ansible_bond0.features.esp_hw_offload'

